# Yii2 override nested config parameters

Tags: php, merge, configuration, yii2

I merge my configs in this way:

```
$config = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    (require (__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php')),
    (require __DIR__ . '/../config/overrides/web.php')
);
```

Here is the **config/web.php**

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'categories' => ['parsingFailure'],
                    'logVars' => [],
                    'message' => [
                        'from' => ['system@host.com'],
                        'to' => ['support@host.com'],
                        'subject' => 'Message parsing failure',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        //....some more components
    ]
];
```

Here is the override that I try to apply **config/overrides/web.php**

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [],
        ],
    ]
];
```

So, my goal is to disable logging in local configuration. 
Of course it does not work, since the behavior of **array_merge** is different and nothing gets overridden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#merge()-detail):

> Recursive merging will be conducted if both arrays have an element of array type and are having the same key. [...] You can use `yii\helpers\UnsetArrayValue` object to unset value from previous array or `yii\helpers\ReplaceArrayValue` to force replace former value instead of recursive merging.

So your second array should be

```
'targets' =>  new \yii\helpers\ReplaceArrayValue([]),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ArrayHelper to override something it can't be an array in both arrays. So for example you can change `'targets' => []` to `'targets' => null`

Comment: It wont work, because the result of such merging will be a total overriding of all components, that only components['log'] is remained.

Comment: Yes, it will override all components, because default `array_merge` will merge only first level of array. If you want ArrayHelper to override something it can't be an array in both arrays. So for example you can change `'targets' => []` to `'targets' => null`

Comment: +1 For the last statement. The first part is incorrect and should be removed since the first array has other elements in the `components` array.

Comment: If you set targets = null, then error will occur when targets will be processed by Logger where it expected to be an array.